# Use of constant reference as return type

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I am reading Meyer's Effective C++ and in the first part there is a function definition:

```
template<class T>
inline const T& max(const T& a, const T& b)
{ return a > b ? a : b; }
```

Why not just return T? Why const T&?

Comment: Does the book go on to discuss the issues surrounding this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` is a large or complex type, then you might not want the cost of copying it to return by value. If it's not copyable, then it can't be returned by value at all.

Returning a reference gives the caller the option of copying it or not; although (as mentioned in comments) you need to be careful if you keep hold of the reference beyond the end of the statement that calls the function, if either argument is a temporary.

Comment: Would this apply to C++11 too?

Comment: "Returning a reference" also gives you the rope to hang yourself on a temporary :-)

Comment: Naturally it also applies to C++11 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Comment: @KerrekSB: Indeed, I was just adding a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are `const T &` so this function returns one of its arguments, which is exactly what a `max` function is supposed to do.  There is no reason to return a copy instead.

Answer (score 0):

At least there are two reasons.

Creating the temporary object that will be returned can be a constly operation.

The other reason is that you need sometimes to access the lvalue of the one of the arguments. Consider for example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class A
{
private:
    static size_t count; 
    size_t mID;
public:
    A() : mID( ++count ) {}
    A( const A & ) : mID( ++count ) {}
    size_t getID() const { return mID; }
};

bool operator <( const A &a1, const A &a2 )
{
    return a1.getID() < a2.getID();
}

size_t A::count;

inline A my_max( const A &a, const A &b )
{ 
    return a < b ? b : a; 
}

int main() 
{
    A one;
    A two;

    std::cout << std::max( one, two ).getID() << std::endl;
    std::cout << my_max( one, two ).getID() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output

```
2
3
```

I think that 3 is not what you expected to get.